# В Python cтроку преобразовать в список списков

Tags: python, строки, pandas, list, numpy

Имеется строка, в которой упакован список, а в него - другие списки.  Выглядит так:

```
'[[9.5212002e+00 2.2994974e+00 1.6960284e-01 4.9130162e-03\n  2.5120098e-03 1.4397422e-04]\n [2.0047040e-01 8.8306583e-02 2.1285409e-02 2.1209638e-04\n  1.0441074e-04 8.9022797e-06]\n [3.8182934e-06 2.8455556e-08 4.8252660e-09 4.7520099e-10\n  1.2675896e-10 1.5909142e-11]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]]'
```

Это ячейка в одной колонке датафрейма:

```
mel = data.mel # колонка
mel[0]         # ячейка в колонке
```

Как видно, оператор перевода строки '\n' встречается как внутри вложенного списка, так и между вложенными списками.

Необходимо получить список списков. Нечто вроде:

```
array([[-659.8619   , -659.8619   , -614.31775  , -543.81165  ,
        -554.7433   , -554.75507  ],
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,   -1.51804  , 12.63958  ,
          12.267615 ,    8.20528  ]], dtype=float32)
```

Как добиться решения?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy для простоты примера убрал `...` - в реальной задаче на выводе в массиве в силу его размера поставлены пропуски

Comment: Эту задачу гораздо проще и правильнее решать с другой стороны. Каким образом вы получили данные строки? И как вы создаёте исходный фрейм?

Comment: @MaxU эти строки пришли из файла csv - они у меня имеются изначально

Comment: А CSV как создаётся?

Comment: @MaxU получен извне - это mel-коэффициенты записи голосов. Взял готовые. В данном случае в строке представлена одна запись одного голоса

Comment: Эти данные - результат печати на экран или преобразования матриц в  строки, т.е. результат вызова str(matrix) или repr(matrix). Ни один софт не будет так обрабатывать данные, потому что это ломает данные. Восстановить исходные данные из "..." - физически невозможно

Comment: @MaxU я убрал для примера эти три точки. В реальности они не выводятся, но в памяти лежат. Как получили данные: взяли голос и извлекли из него коэффициенты с помощью библиотеки. Могу предположить, что использовалась librosa. Также была предобработка - возможно, она "сломала" корректное отображение (я для эксперимента записал свой голос и преобразовал его в mel-коэффициенты с использованием librosa: получилось как раз так, как привел в последнем списке, т.е. нормально)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно элементарно заменить пробелы на `,` и спарсить строку:

```
import re
from json import loads
import numpy as np

a = np.array(loads(re.sub(r"\s+", r",", s)))
```

результат:

```
In [149]: a
Out[149]:
array([[9.5212002e+00, 2.2994974e+00, 1.6960284e-01, 4.9130162e-03,
        2.5120098e-03, 1.4397422e-04],
       [2.0047040e-01, 8.8306583e-02, 2.1285409e-02, 2.1209638e-04,
        1.0441074e-04, 8.9022797e-06],
       [3.8182934e-06, 2.8455556e-08, 4.8252660e-09, 4.7520099e-10,
        1.2675896e-10, 1.5909142e-11],
       [3.9644172e-05, 1.5620193e-37, 8.9472133e-38, 6.2457425e-38,
        4.8144636e-38, 2.8480850e-38],
       [3.9644172e-05, 1.5620193e-37, 8.9472133e-38, 6.2457425e-38,
        4.8144636e-38, 2.8480850e-38],
       [3.9644172e-05, 1.5620193e-37, 8.9472133e-38, 6.2457425e-38,
        4.8144636e-38, 2.8480850e-38]])
```

Comment: по-моему элегантное решение. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Разобрать строку на токены - `[` или `]` или `слово без пробелов и скобок`.
2. Рекурсивным спуском восстановить иерархию списков. Заодно слова переводим в числа.
3. Из вложенных списков создать `np.array`.

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import re

def tokens(s):
    return (m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'\[|\]|[^\s\[\]]+', s))


def parse(s):

    def parse(it):
        for t in it:
            if t == ']':
                break
            elif t == '[':
                yield tuple(parse(it))
            else:
                try:
                    yield float(t)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

    return tuple(parse(tokens(s)))


def read_np_array(s):
    return np.array(*parse(s))


s = '[[9.5212002e+00 2.2994974e+00 1.6960284e-01 4.9130162e-03\n  2.5120098e-03 1.4397422e-04]\n [2.0047040e-01 8.8306583e-02 2.1285409e-02 2.1209638e-04\n  1.0441074e-04 8.9022797e-06]\n [3.8182934e-06 2.8455556e-08 4.8252660e-09 4.7520099e-10\n  1.2675896e-10 1.5909142e-11]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]\n [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38\n  4.8144636e-38 2.8480850e-38]]'

print(read_np_array(s))
```

> ```
> $ python parse.py
> [[9.5212002e+00 2.2994974e+00 1.6960284e-01 4.9130162e-03 2.5120098e-03
>   1.4397422e-04]
>  [2.0047040e-01 8.8306583e-02 2.1285409e-02 2.1209638e-04 1.0441074e-04
>   8.9022797e-06]
>  [3.8182934e-06 2.8455556e-08 4.8252660e-09 4.7520099e-10 1.2675896e-10
>   1.5909142e-11]
>  [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38 4.8144636e-38
>   2.8480850e-38]
>  [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38 4.8144636e-38
>   2.8480850e-38]
>  [3.9644172e-05 1.5620193e-37 8.9472133e-38 6.2457425e-38 4.8144636e-38
>   2.8480850e-38]]
> ```

Comment: Вы дали отличный результат. Еще момент: где в коде прописать ()join.(), чтобы появились запятые между цифрами во внутренних списках и между этими списками?

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев, `print(repr(read_np_array(s)))`. Хотя сам вопрос настораживает. :)

Comment: рождественский подарок: я этой функцией не пользовался ни разу. Хорошая находка под елкой. Благодарю ))

Comment: разбираюсь с кодом  и все ж таки троеточие там пришло лишним. Залез в регулярки, но завяз. (( Как трансформировать Ваш код, чтобы выкинуть также и троеточия? Буду благодарен

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев, добавил `try/except` вокруг преобразования слова в число. Многоточия теперь отсеиваются.